# UTL_FILE Error during writing data to file

Tags: oracle, plsql

Team,
Below is the sample code, while trying to write data from cursor to file -

I am currently using 11g Express Edition

```
CTEST is the directory created  and empdata is the declaration variable.

SQL>  declare
  2      empData utl_file.file_type;
  3       BEGIN
  4       empData := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CTEST','empdata.csv','W');
  5       for emp IN ( select table_name from user_tables) LOOP
  6        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(empData,emp.table_name);
  7      END LOOP;
  8       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(empData);
  9      end;
 10  /
    empData utl_file.file_type;
            *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_FILE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 13:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 6:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have the privileges on UTL_FILE,

from sys user run this command,

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO <username> ;
```

Comment: Thankyou, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Pls mark the answer correct if it has helped you :)